# parse.com "error: unauthorized" when trying to save object

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am using masterkey yet still getting unauthorized error when trying to save an object. Can anyone figure out why? I can see that "started making ticket" gets logged. and the request.params all pull the correct information.

Also, a side question...I am under the impression that if response.error is executed it stops the code, but then will send that error message to the function that called this cloud code and then run any error handling there. I have a console.log error message in this cloud code, and then an error alert in the function that called it. I am getting the console log to show, but not the alert. Is my assumption wrong in that it doesnt get passed, and that it actually just terminates the entire thing upon executing response.error?

```
Parse.Cloud.define("createRecord", function(request, response) {
    var caseClass = Parse.Object.extend("Cases");
    var ticket = new caseClass();
    console.log("started making ticket");
    ticket.title = request.params.title;
    ticket.category = request.params.category;
    ticket.priority = request.params.priority;
    ticket.description = request.params.cmnts;
    ticket.save(null, {useMasterKey: true}).then(function() {
        response.success();
    }, function(error) {
        response.error("error response: " + error.message);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Parse.Cloud.run("createRecord", {something: yourData}, {...
```

and:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("createRecord", function (request, response) {
    var something = request.params.something;
    var caseClass = Parse.Object.extend("Cases");
    var ticket = new caseClass();
    console.log("started making ticket");
    ticket.set("title", something.title);
    ticket.set("category", something.category);
    ticket.set("priority", something.priority);
    ticket.set("description", something.cmnts);
    ticket.save(null, {useMasterKey: true}).then(function() {
        response.success();
    }, function(error) {
        response.error("error response: " + error.message);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I would love to try it but the command line tool keeps telling me to update and I cant figure out how. As soon as i get it updated I will test this out and see. The error seems to be coming from not have the right authorization to save/isnt recognizing the master key. Do you think calling the request.params while trying to save it was creating issues with authorization?

Comment: "You can call Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey() before making calls to Parse", I have some code with request.params and it works with Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

Comment: I tried that as well. I put that line in before

    var caseClass = Parse.Object.extend("Cases");

and it still processed the same way and through the same errors

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it took me a while to be able to deploy cloud code again. I tried that change and it still isnt working. Its not even running that cloud function according to the logs.

Comment: Tested it some more and here is where I am at: If i try to pass an object as a parameter when running cloud code, it will cause the cloud code to not run at all. I sent each value as a separate value and i was able to run it, but I structured it similar to how you did. I created a ticket object inside the cloud code, did the list of ticket.set() for each value, and then did ticket.save and I am still getting the same unauthorized error. What am I missing? I also just added Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey() as the first line in the cloud code for good measure. Shouldnt that give me full access?

Comment: I might have figured out where the error is coming from but still dont have a clue how to fix it. I am handling login browser side, but when I redirect pages it loses its current User. I think its trying to apply the master key to a user, but user is undefined, so it still says its unauthorized. How can I tranfer login credentials from page to page after a redirect?